# Xcode stuck in running playground

Tags: swift, xcode

So every time I try running my code in the playground it throws the following error:

```
Playground execution failed:

error: /var/folders/1y/636dsz5d60s21x7j9h9517g4001lh5/T/playground3-6941f6..swift:3:37: error: expected ',' in #sourceLocation directive
#sourceLocation(file: "MyPlayground".playground", line: 1)
                                    ^    
error: /var/folders/1y/636dsz5d60s21x7j9h9517g4001lh5/T/playground3-6941f6..swift:3:48: error: unterminated string literal
#sourceLocation(file: "MyPlayground".playground", line: 1)
```

Please Help me...

Comment: There are three double quotes. It should work after you remove the `"` before the `.playground` so it will become `"MyPlayground.playground"`

Comment: Share your code so that it may help people to get the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with Playground and the **problem was the fact that Xcode is constantly syncing with iCloud.**
Sometimes because of buggy behavior or poor connection is stucks on "Running"

Just go to:

System Preferences - Apple ID - Apps on this Mac using iCloud- iCloud Drive - Options- And then uncheck "Playground"

That little trick prevents syncing and resolves the frozen "Running".

[image: Uncheck Playground from syncing]